# CSS to show a menu properly

Tags: css

I have a category table which maintains infinite level of subcategories. It looks like the one shown in the following [snap shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StrRf.png).

[image]

In the above table, the third column displays parent name. When mouse button is hovered over the parent name, a menu is displayed that shows tree structure of the category in different colours.

When the menu is popped up, it is overlapped by the parent name below it (I can't express it in words properly so please, look at the image above). What CSS or other thins should be used so that the menu is displayed properly?

Parent names are displayed in `<ul><li></li></ul>` as follows

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div style='width:53px;cursor:hand;text-align:left; background-color:white; border:none; color:black; font-size:small;'>

         <?php echo htmlspecialchars($name, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?>

        </div>                            
   </li>
</ul>
```

---

In case, the CSS that displays the entire menu is required, it is as follows.

```
.jqueryslidemenu{font:bold 9px Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;color:#fff;width: 100%;text-align:left;z-index:99999}
.jqueryslidemenu ul{margin: 0;padding: 0px;list-style-type: none;z-index:99999}
.jqueryslidemenu ul li{position: relative;display: inline;float: left;z-index:99999}
.jqueryslidemenu ul li a{font:bold 12px Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;display: block;background:#000;color: #fff;padding: 3px 3px;text-decoration: none;z-index:99999}
* html .jqueryslidemenu ul li a{display: inline-block;z-index:99999}
.jqueryslidemenu ul li a:link, .jqueryslidemenu ul li a:visited{color: #fff;text-decoration: none;z-index:99999}

.jqueryslidemenu ul li a:hover{background:#000;text-decoration:none;color: #03C;z-index:99999}
.jqueryslidemenu ul li ul{position: absolute;left: 0;display: block;visibility: hidden;z-index:99999}
.jqueryslidemenu ul li ul li{display: list-item;float: none;z-index:99999}
.jqueryslidemenu ul li ul li ul{top:0;z-index:99999}
.jqueryslidemenu ul li ul li a{font:bold 9px Tahoma, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;width: 140px;margin: 0;padding: 6px;border-top-width: 0;border-bottom: 1px solid gray;z-index:99999}
.jqueryslidemenuz ul li ul li a:hover{color:#fff; background:#000;z-index:99999}
.downarrowclass{position: absolute;top: 8px;right: 7px;display:none;z-index:99999}
.rightarrowclass{position: absolute;top: 6px;right: 5px;z-index:99999}
```

Comment: have you checked that the z-index of the overlapping element that in the picture says "JSF" is less than that of the actual dropdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a z-index issue.

Could it be because this line in your css:

```
.jqueryslidemenu ul li a
```

Has a z-index of 99999 which is making the parent link text show above the cascading pop-up menu? Lower it's z-index to 1 and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the z-index is set to 99999 meaning that it forces the item to be the top most.  Give that particular element (ul li) a z-index of auto or 1.  Do this by giving that column a specific class like below.

html:

```
<li class="behind"></li>
```

css:

```
li.behind{
    z-index: auto;
}
```